# How to force stop doParallel %dopar% calculations in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, doparallel

My shiny app does clustering using `%dopar%` from doParallel library. There is one thing that bothers me: if an operation takes, for example, 10 minutes to calculate, but user closes the window of an app before it's done  -  calculations will continue to happen until they're finished.

What I'm trying to do is to force stop them on session end. I tried to do something like this

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopCluster(clu)
    print("stopped")
})
```

to stop calculations on window closure, but it is evaluated after the calculations are done. Here is a test app i'm trying to get it to work on:

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(doParallel)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    wd <- getwd()
    rv <- reactiveValues()
    clu <- makeCluster(2)
    registerDoParallel(clu)


    observeEvent(input$loadDataButton, {
        rv$listDF <- readRDS(paste0(wd, "/iris15k.RData"))
    })
    observeEvent(input$clusterButton, {
        if (input$clusterButton >= 1) {
            df <- rv$listDF
            rv$resultTime <- system.time(
                rv$r <- foreach(icount(100)) %dopar% {
                    table <- kmeans(as.data.frame(df), centers = 3)
                }
            )
    }
})
observeEvent(rv$listDF, {
    output$done <- renderText("Done loading!")
})

observeEvent(rv$resultTime, {
    output$time <- renderText(c("Done caltulating, time:", rv$resultTime))
    print(rv$resultTime)
})


session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopCluster(clu)
        print("stopped")
    })
})
```

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
 actionButton(
     inputId = "loadDataButton",
     label = "load data"
 ),
 actionButton(
     inputId = "clusterButton",
     label = "Do clustering"
 ),
 textOutput("done"),
 textOutput("time")
))
```

`iris15k.RData` is a simple iris dataset with replicated rows to make the operation longer.
There is a way to write a bash script that will do the job and kill the processes in very straight way, but I'd rather do it from R side as I know little of it and it seems to be right to get it work withing an app code.
Any suggestions?